# React: Missing property in state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, setstate

So I started learning React and after doing some basics (counters, todo lists) I decided to do something more challenging; a chessboard with pieces that can be moved around by clicking. My main component is `Chessboard`. It then renders `Tiles` that may contain a `Piece`. Information about the game is stored in `Chessboard's` state, looking like this:

```
interface State {
  board: Record<string, pieceInterface>;
  isPieceMoving: boolean;
  movingPieceId: string;
}
```

I handle moving pieces in `Chessboard's` method `onTileClick(id: string)`. It is passed to a `Tile` as a prop and when a tile is clicked it's called with a tile id (like "a4", "f6", "h3"). It has following logic. Game can be in two states: I can be currently moving a piece or I can currently do nothing and then start moving a piece by clicking on it. When I start moving a piece I store it's ID (or rather an ID of a tile on witch piece stands) in `state.movingPieceId`. When I try to place it I check if the tile is empty and then change `state.board` accordingly. Here is my code:

```
onTileClick = (id: string): void => {
  if (!this.state.isPieceMoving) {
    if (this.state.board[id]) {
      this.setState({
        isPieceMoving: true,
        movingPieceId: id,
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (!this.state.board[id]) {
      this.setState((state) => {
        let board: Record<string, pieceInterface> = state.board;
        const piece: pieceInterface = board[state.movingPieceId];

        delete board[state.movingPieceId];
        board[id] = piece;

        // console.log(board[id]);
        // console.lob(board);

        const isPieceMoving: boolean = false;
        const movingPieceId: string = "";

        return { board, isPieceMoving, movingPieceId };
      });
    }
  }
};
```

The first part works just fine. But in the second there is some bug, that I cannot find. When I uncomment this console logs the output looks like this (I want to move a piece from "a2" to "a3"):

```
Object { "My piece representation" }
Object {
    a1: { "My piece representation" },
    a3: undefined,
    a7: { "My piece representation" },
    ...
}
```

My code properly "takes" clicked piece from "a2" (board has no "a2" property) but it apparently does **not** place it back. Even when printing `board[id]` gives correct object! I was moving logging line `console.log(board)` up to see where bug happens. And even when I put it directly behind else it still was saying that "a3" was `undefined`.

I spend hours trying to understand what was happening. I tried to emulate this fragment of code in console, but there it always worked! Can anybody explain to me what am I doing wrong? Is this some weird React's setState mechanism that I haven't learned yet? Or is it some basic javascript thing, that I am not aware of? Any help would we wonderful, because I cannot move on and do anything else while being stuck here.

EDIT #1

Ok. So I was able to fix this bug by **deep copying** `state.board` into `board` (inspiredy by @Linda Paiste's comment). I just used simple JSON stringify/parse hack:

```
let board: Record<string, pieceInterface> = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.board));
```

This fixes the bug but I have no idea why. I will keep this question open, so maybe someone will explain to me **what** and **why** was wrong with my previous code.

EDIT #2

Ok. Thanks to @Linda's explanation and reading [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) i finally understood what I was doing wrong. Linda made detailed explanation in an answer below (the accepted one). Thank you all very much!

Comment: Is id equal to "a3" when the console logging is performed? Could you verify that?

Comment: @ViktorW Yes it is.

Comment: `delete board[state.movingPieceId];` <-- this is a mutation of state!

Comment: Your aliased `board` variable refers to the same object as `state.board`, so you cannot mutate it in any way.

Comment: Yes, and that could perhaps be considered bad practice, but I don't see how that could be the issue. The state object itself should not be modified, but React won't really care about if you modify nested objects.

Comment: The issue that the field a3 looks empty when logged seems outright impossible, if id is "a3" and piece is something not undefined. The only thing I can think of is if board is some kind of funky object, not just a regular object.

Comment: But I successfully deleted old id. Also I heard that using setState with a function makes `state` a copy of `this.state`, so I can mutate it.

Comment: @ViktorW What?  Of course it's the issue.  They `delete` a property from the object in `state.board`, and when they log the object it is missing that property.

Comment: They delete the field "a2" in board, and set the field "a3". a2 is indeed missing, as it should, but a3 is also undefined.

Comment: Could you take a look at this, here it works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/mLpdh53a/

Comment: One thing that actually could cause the issue is if onTileClick() gets called twice at the same time. The function setState is asynchronous, meaning that you should not rely on checking the state and then calling setState based on that state - the state may change between the check and the update. If that were to happen, it would cause this issue. You should move the `if (!this.state.board[id]) {` inside your setState callback function. If you based on that check realize you should not update, simply `return state;`

Comment: @Aleksander try this: `this.setState((state) => ({
          isPieceMoving: false,
          movingPieceId: '',
          board: {
            ...state.board,
            [state.movingPieceId]: undefined,
            [id]: state.movingPieceId,
          }
        })`

Comment: I found a hack that fixes my problem (don't know why). Edited the post. This has to have something with what @Linda was suggesting at the beginning. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Aleksander I am writing an answer but you **do** know why, don't you?  When you create a deep copy you aren't mutating the state anymore.  Does my code in the previous comment work?

Comment: @Alexander this is a good guide about updating without mutating: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#immutable-update-patterns

Comment: @Alexander Regarding this "I heard that using `setState` with a function makes `state` a copy of `this.state`, so I can mutate it." That's incorrect.  The advantage of using a callback is that the `state` argument is guaranteed to be the current value. Per the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate "`state` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. **It should not be directly mutated.** Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from `state` and `props`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem: Mutation of State

```
let board: Record<string, pieceInterface> = state.board;
```

You are creating a new variable `board` that refers to the same board object as the one in your actual state.  Then you mutate that object:

```
delete board[state.movingPieceId];
board[id] = piece;
```

This is an illegal mutation of state because any changes to `board` will also impact `this.state.board`.

#### Solution: Create a New Board

Any array or object that you want to change in your state needs to be a new version of that object.

Your deep copy of `board` works because this new `board` is totally independent of your `state` so you can mutate it without impacting the state.  But this is not the best solution.  It is inefficient and will cause unnecessary renders because every piece object will be a new version as well.

We just need to copy the objects which are changing: the `state` and the `board`.

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  isPieceMoving: false,
  movingPieceId: '',
  board: {
    // copy everything that isn't changing
    ...state.board,
    // remove the moving piece from its current position
    [state.movingPieceId]: undefined,
    // place the moving piece in its new location
    [id]: state.board[state.movingPieceId],
  }
}));
```

Your typescript type for the `board` property of `State` should be `Partial<Record<string, pieceInterface>>` because not every slot on the board has a piece in it.

Very ugly but functional [Code Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/moving-chess-pieces-ohlgz?file=/src/App.tsx)

#### Edit: About the setState Callback

> I heard that using `setState` with a function makes `state` a copy of `this.state`, so I can mutate it.

That is incorrect.  You should never mutate state and this is no exception.  The advantage of using a callback is that the `state` argument is guaranteed to be the current value, which is important because `setState` is asynchronous and there might be multiple pending updates.

Here's what the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) say (emphasis added):

> `state` is a **reference** to the component state at the time the change is being applied. **It should not be directly mutated.** Instead, changes should be represented by building a **new object** based on the input from `state` and `props`."
>
> Both `state` and `props` received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date.